# Es realmente necesario capturar la excepción de NimbusLookAndFeel

Tags: java, java-swing, look-and-feel

Lo digo porque la clase NimbusLookAndFeel esta incluido en el paquete de Swing, y no es algo externo a Java, seria como decir que MetalLookAndFeel de la nada puede no estar, o que el paquete Swing no esta incluido en el JDK, y arroja una excepción (por ejemplo JavaFX - OpenJDK).

Vi que Nimbus no es algo exclusivo de un sistema operativo, como puede ser GTKLookAndFeel, o WindowsLookAndFeel

Ademas me parece mas bonito ver el código así

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
}
```

Que verlo así

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- Es realmente necesario? o puedo lanzarla hacia arriba?
- Alguna vez a ustedes les lanzo un error por NimbusLookAndFeel o MetalLookAndFeel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lo personal, todas las veces que he usado NimbusLookAndFeel integrándolo en Swing, nunca he recibido ninguna excepción, sin embargo, considero que no está demás que controles alguna posible excepción usando el bloque try, aparte de ser una buena práctica.

Answer (score 0):

Solo para dar un poco mas de información que antes no tenia, es que el método `setLookAndFeel` tiene que lanzar una excepción ya que hay algunos `PLAF` no son soportados por todos los sistemas, por ejemplo `GTK` o `Window`, o cualquier otro con restricciones en el método `isSupportedLookAndFeel`.

`Nimbus` y `Metal` simplemente retornan true, lo que hace siempre compatible y no halla ningún problema si se captura o no, aun así como dijo Ruben en su respuesta, es bueno seguir las buenas practicas del lenguaje Java y capturar las excepciones, por eso la di por aceptada sin que resuelva completamente mi duda.

GTKLookAndFeel utiliza una herramienta donde se da cuanta si es compatible o no con el sistema, se puede ver en la misma clase en el OpenJDK.

WindowLookAndFeel por lo que puede ver de un repositorio de GitHub, pregunta si el sistema es Windows o no...

```
public boolean isNativeLookAndFeel() {
    return OSInfo.getOSType() == OSInfo.OSType.WINDOWS;
}

public boolean isSupportedLookAndFeel() {
    return isNativeLookAndFeel();
}
```

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.desktop/windows/classes/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsLookAndFeel.java

Para verificar todo lo que dije, se puede cambiar el método de Nimbus y retornar `false`, esto causa una excepción `UnsupportedLookAndFeelException` y se carga `MetalLookAndFeel`

```
NimbusLookAndFeel nimbus = new NimbusLookAndFeel() {
    @Override
    public boolean isSupportedLookAndFeel() {
        return false;
    }
};
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(nimbus);
```

- Es realmente necesario? o puedo lanzarla hacia arriba?

> Cuando se trata de Metal o Nimbus no es realmente necesario, el método setLookAndFeel, esta preparado para lanzar una excepción sea cual sea el PLAF, para evitar problemas con los que realmente necesitan una captura, aun así es mejor seguir las buenas practicas de Java y capturar las excepciones.

- Alguna vez a ustedes les lanzo un error por NimbusLookAndFeel o MetalLookAndFeel?

> Es imposible que te lance una excepción cualquiera de estos dos LookAndFeel.